# Descartes's Rule of Signs Lemma

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you prove this lemma?
if $p(x)$ has real coefficient , and if $p(a)=0$ where $a>0$ , then $p(x)$ has at least one more sign variation than the quotient $q(x)$.Moreover, when the difference in the number of sign variation is greater than $1$, the difference is always an odd number

Comment: See [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/fta/ROS2.shtml) proof by induction linked from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) page.

Comment: What do you mean by the quotient $q(x)$ ? A polynomial which divides $p(x)$ ?

Comment: @BazlyZuczek i name the quotient as $q(x)$ .you can name the quotient whatever you want

Comment: OK, but it you mean $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$ then your conclusion is not satisfied. $p(x)=x(x^2+1)$ and $q(x)=x.$

Comment: your dividen is must be $x-a$ where $a>0$. $(x^2+1)$ is not in the form $x-a$

Comment: OK. What about $p(x)=(x-a)^2.$ and $q(x)=x-a$ ?

Comment: $p(x)$ has 2 sign of variations and $q(x)$ has 1 sign of variations. Which is satisfy the lemma because the number of sign variations of $p(x)$ has 1 more sign variations than $q(x)$

Comment: What do you mean by the sign variation ? I thought the sign variation of its values.

Comment: sign of variation means whenever adjacent coefficients have opposite signs for example $p(x)=x^2-1$ it has 1 sign of variations another example $p(x)=-3x^2+2x-8$ has 2 sign of variations another example $p(x)=2x^3+4x^2-8x-1$ has 1 sign of variations

Comment: I have tried to answer your question as elementary as possible. Perhaps there are  reasonings simpler than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to consider the case $p(1)=0,$ by applying the substitution $q(x)=p(ax).$ Then $q(x)$ and $q(x)/(x-1)$ have the same number of sign changes as $p(x)$ and $p(x)/(x-a)$ respectively. Let
$${p(x)\over x-1}=a_{n}x^{n-1}+a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\ldots +a_2x+a_1.$$ Set $a_{n+1}=a_{0}=0.$ Then
$$p(x)=(a_{n}-a_{n+1})x^{n}+(a_{n-1}-a_{n})x^{n-1}+\ldots + (a_0-a_1)x +(a_{-1}-a_0).$$
Consider the piecewise linear function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $[-1,n+1]$ such that $f(j)=a_j$ and $f(x)$ is linear on each interval $(j-1,j),$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n+1.$
This function vanishes at the endpoints. The number of  sign changes of $p(x)$ is equal the number of local extrema of $f(x)$ in the interval $(-1,n+1).$ On the other hand the number of sign changes of $p(x)/(x-1)$ is equal the number of sign changes of the function $f(x)$ in $(-1,n+1).$

Any time the function $f(x)$ crosses the  value $0,$ the corresponding point is located between two local extrema. Therefore the number of sign changes of $p(x)$ is greater than that of $p(x)/(x-1)$ by at least $1.$

Let $x_1<x_2<\ldots <x_k$ be all the points, where $f(x)$ changes sign.
Set $x_0=-1$ and $x_{k+1}=n+1.$  Observe that between any two consecutive points $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ the function $f(x)$ has an odd number $n_i$ of extrema. Therefore the total number of extrema is equal
$$n_0+n_1+\ldots +n_k.$$
The difference
$$(n_0+n_1+\ldots +n_k)-k=n_0+(n_1-1)+(n_2-1)+\ldots +(n_k-1)$$ is thus an odd number.